# Simulation Nodes Initial set of points behaves strange

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I´m currently following this tutorial (https://youtu.be/RJbLiFTNHnI) and came across some strange behaviour on one of the first set of points that get joined into the Simulation Zone.
On frame 0 the second set of points gets a value of 10 on the y-axis, which leads to this set of points breaking out of the line. I assume the values get added up from the Simulation Input Node and the Capture Attribute node. [image: 2nd Set of Points move further than the rest]

I found a workaround to this by simply switching to just the Simulation Zones input geometry on frame 0[image: this is the workaround setup]

However im still not sure if this is the right way to do it and why those values get added up to 10 on frame 0 but not on the following frames. I would be happy if someone could tell me how the vector add node behaves so strange in this example and if there is a smarter solution to this then switching the geometry after frame 0.

This is my first time using StackExchange so sorry for any mistakes!
Thanks in advance!